# Parse: cannot upload file

Tags: java, android, file-upload, parse-platform

I want to make an app which have upload file function. But the problem is, I unable to find where did I do wrong.

First, choose the file

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Select file");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                        RESULT_LOAD_FILE);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // here
        }
```

I guess there's no problem when choosing the file based on the logcat. But...

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, requestCode+"/"+RESULT_LOAD_FILE+"/"+resultCode+"/"+RESULT_OK);

    if (data != null) Log.d(TAG, data.toString());
    else Log.d(TAG, "data null");

    // get file name
    String fileNameSegments[] = filePath.split("/");
    fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

    // convert it to byte
    byte[] fileByte = fileName.getBytes();

    // Create the ParseFile
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileByte);

    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
    file.saveInBackground();

    // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
    ParseObject fileupload = new ParseObject("FileUpload");

    // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
    fileupload.put("FileName", fileName);

    // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
    fileupload.put("DocFile", file);

    // Create the class and the columns
    fileupload.saveInBackground();

    // Show a simple toast message
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The logcat show `requestCode`, `RESULT_LOAD_FILE`, `resultCode` and `RESULT_OK` 1, 1, -1 and -1 respectively. And the data is not null, as in logcat: `Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/0A09-1112:Download/Contact n Tort.pdf flg=0x1 }`

After I click the .pdf file, it triggered the toast `Something went wrong` but I can't find what the reason.

---

EDITED:
Throw null pointer exception after convert the file path to byte, when I remove the try catch block

Comment: What is the message for the exception raised ??

Comment: @MoNazemi `Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content:.......... }} to activity {com.example...........MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Well it says the variable `filePath` is null, where do you initialise that ??

Comment: @MoNazemi `String selectedFile = data.getData().getPath();`

Comment: huh !? Why are you doing this `String fileNameSegments[] = filePath.split("/");` then ?

Comment: @MoNazemi chill. I'm just a beginner. I'll try comment it out then

Comment: Not mad bro ;) fixed now ?

Comment: @MoNazemi not yet, after removed the `selectedFile`

Comment: so what did you remove from code ? Can you update your code and error messages again.

Comment: @MoNazemi I removed `String selectedFile = data.getData().getPath();` and try-catch block for a while

Comment: But I do not see where `filePath` object has been initialised ??

Comment: @MoNazemi solved. thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
 Uri uri = data.getData();
            // get path
            filePath = uri.getPath();

            // get file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = filePath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

            // convert it to byte
            byte[] fileByte = fileName.getBytes();

            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileByte);

            // Upload the file into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();

            // Create a New Class called "FileUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject fileUpload = new ParseObject("FileUpload");

            // Create a column named "FileName" and set the string
            fileUpload.put("FileName", fileName);

            Log.d(TAG, "image file");
            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            fileUpload.put("DocFile", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            fileUpload.saveInBackground();

            Log.d(TAG, "toast");
            // Show a simple toast message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

though the class not created in parse dashboard but I guess that need another post.