# Parse: class not created in dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform

Following from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220048/parse-cannot-upload-file/33228435#33228435), now I have another problem. I followed the [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-image-upload-tutorial/) of upload image to parse, and added some code to make it upload all kind of file. Even though the toast `File uploaded` was triggered, the class `FileUpload` is not created in dashboard. It's confusing even though I followed the tutorial.

Update: I commented out `fileUpload.put("DocFile", file)` and able to create the class but the file, of course, not saved in that class.

Comment: please check logcat there is some error on logcat

Comment: `W/System﹕ Ignoring header Content-Type because its value was null.` you mean this one?

Answer (score 0):

Save Obejct with callback. You will get save response in `done` method

```
fileUpload.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e !=null)
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error :"+e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: it didn't trigger the toast. I replaced `fileUpload.saveInBackground()` with code you gave.

Comment: I add `else Log.d(TAG, "e is null");` but it didn't printed in logcat

Comment: debug your code and see that  `onActivityResult` called or not. also save response